# Where is the Dremora treasure in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After freeing the Dremora in the Dark Midden Under the Winterhold College I was given a vague map of where the Dremora's treasure was located. (Somewhere near Winterhold) After searching near the landmarks shown on the map, I still can't find the right spot where the treasure is hidden. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you set Velehk free?

Comment: @IPhantasmI Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to pilgrims trench by winter hold, there should be an island with a talos statue on it. Stand in front of it on the beach and your loot will appear.